# Issue with .on() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make an MVC for training purposes and I am following a tutorial for that which is rather old. The implementation in the tutorial was made using **live()** but I decided to use jQuery 2.1.1 and have to implement **on()** method. I made a small use case for clarification.

1. I can insert new elements on the page while adding them in the DB
2. I can delete preloaded elements which existed in the DB at page load both from the DB and DOM
3. **I can not** remove elements which are added live neither from the db nor the DOM.

this is my entire code regarding that.

```
$(function(){

$.get('dashboard/xhrGetListings', function(o){

    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++ )
    {
        $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o[i].text + '<a class="del" rel="' + o[i].id + '" href="#">x</a></div>');
    }

    $('.del').on("click", function() {
        delItem = $(this);
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing', {'id': id}, function(o) {
            delItem.parent().remove(); // THIS IS NOT EXECUTED AT ALL
        }, 'json');

        return false;
    });
}, 'json');
```

//Not necesarly relevant, it just helps for code clarity

```
$('#randomInsert').on("submit", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(data);

    $.post(url, data, function(o) {
        $('#listInserts').append('<div>' + o.text + ' <a class="del" rel="' + o.id + '" href="#">X</a></div>');
    }, 'json');

    return false;
});
```

});

Another issue that I'm not focussing on at this point is that if I delete the parent inside the $.post method (as shown in the code above) it's not deleted, only if I move that line outside of the post method. Any clarification on that would be also very appreciated.

Comment: `$.post('dashboard/xhrDeleteListing'...)` does this request complete successfully? does you console give any errors? check the js debug tools

Comment: yes, that's executed successfully... meaning that the code associated is run, but anything inside the brackets is not executed. (no errors on the console)

Comment: the code it calls may have run, but if it does not return HTTP status code 200 OK the function will not be called. your browsers logs all ajax calls, doublecheck the status return of the call in question.

Comment: it returns code 200 for the preloaded elements (which are also deleted), for the newly inserted ones through $('#randomInsert') it does nothing when clicking the delete link.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event delegation` and `event.preventDefault()` it stops the default action

```
$('#listInserts').on("click", '.del' , function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // your code come here
});
```